# Получение общего количества всех позиций в каждой из таблиц (Запрос)

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Имеем вот такие таблички

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- таблица А - это список ИД позиций (ну скажем товаров например)
- таблица Б - в ней указано количество позиций из таблицы А
- таблица В - в ней указано количество позиций из таблицы А

Вопрос: нужно написать запрос в котором будет видно количество позиций по каждой таблице (Б и В) вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я придумал запрос наподобие вот такого:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(count) FROM Б WHERE id = 2),
    (SELECT SUM(count) FROM В WHERE id = 2)
```

Но это даст мне одну запись только по позиции с ИД №2 , а нужно по каждой позиции из таблицы А.

Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(q2.`count`,0) `Б`, COALESCE(q3.`count`,0) `В`
FROM `Таблица А` t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.id, SUM(t2.`count`) `count` 
           FROM `Таблица Б` t2 
           GROUP BY t2.id
          ) q2 ON t1.id = q2.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t3.id, SUM(t3.`count`) `count` 
           FROM `Таблица В` t3
           GROUP BY t3.id
          ) q3 ON t1.id = q3.id
```

Comment: спасибо акина сейчас вы прям реально помогли

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.id, COALESCE(B.count, 0), COALESCE(C.count, 0) FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(count) as count
    FROM B GROUP BY id 
) as B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(count) as count
    FROM C GROUP BY id 
) as C ON A.id = C.id

COALESCE в данном случае заменит значения `null` на 0.
```

Comment: unknown field, ambiquous reference, a то и просто syntax error. Лень думать, что именно выстрелит первым.

Comment: @Akina, по содержанию вопроса понятно, что человек привел эти названия таблиц в пример. Явно разберется. Синтаксис верный. А вам я тоже минусануть могу: в вопросе фигурирует запрос "SELECT SUM(count) FROM Б WHERE id = 2", а у вас таблица называется `Таблица Б`)) Придираться все умеют) Я думал, что тут место не для этого

Comment: Минус я поставил Вам именно за то, что есть у меня и чего нет у Вас - алиасы таблиц и квотирование зарезервированных слов, а также за то, чего нет у меня, но есть у Вас - за дублирование имён. Так что Ваше *Синтаксис верный* не соответствует действительность чуть менее чем полностью.

Comment: @Akina, вы не представляете, но создал в MS SQL 2012 таблицы с такими именами и такими именами колонок и ... запрос рабочий) Зря время только потратил)) Давайте закончим спор)

Comment: @Akina А я проверил этот запрос на MySQL и он то же абсолютно рабочий. Никакого дублирования имен тут нет и быть не может. Да, соглашусь, что на некоторых СУБД `count` на до бы квотировать, НО это должен делать сам ТС исходя из того какая у него СУБД. Ваш вариант с обратными апострофами будет работать только на MySQL, у других СУБД другое квотирование.

Comment: Боже, как же я хайпанул)